# Multi step form through Ajax and Jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have written this code so that I can make a multi-step form and load and submit the data through AJAX.

The code is running well for the first form submission, but on the second attempt the page reloads itself. Can someone help me?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery.ajax({
    type: "post",
    url: 'index.php'
  }).done(function(msg) {
    $('#main-container').html(msg);
    index();
  })

  function index() {
    $('#myForm').submit(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var formData = $('#main-container').find('form').serialize();
      console.log(formData);
      jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'index.php',
        data: formData
      }).done(function(msg2) {
        console.log(msg2)
        $('#main-container').html(msg2);
      });
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: Assuming each AJAX request reloads the `#myForm` element, then you probably just need to use a delegated event handler: https://stackoverflow.com/q/203198/519413

Comment: i tried it but the page at second click of button relaodes it self that's creating a problem to me..how can i stop the page from reloading

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#This is how it is done#

```js
$.ajax({ //here i have inculded the php file where i am holding all the multi step form data in other page which i am going to show to the user
  type: "GET",
  url:'index.php'
}).done(function(msg) {
  $('#main-container').html(msg);
  nextBtn();
  backBtn();
})
    

function nextBtn() { //this is the next btn or you may call the submit btn 
  $(document).on('click', ".next", function () {
    var formData = $('#myForm').serialize();
    console.log(formData);
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url:'index.php',
      data: formData
    }).done(function(msg2) {
      console.log(msg2)
      $('#main-container').html(msg2);
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Comment: yes you are right but actually i am new at this just a student..so